# Assistance with path for uploading multiple images in db in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need some assistance with how to save path for multiple images saved in 'upload' folder in a table. I am totally lost here.

I have this app which uploads multiple pictures perfect, but they are not linked with db anywhere.

This is controller which is actually a callback_ function:

```
    private $_uploaded;
    public function fileupload_check() {
    $number_of_files = sizeof($_FILES['uploadedimages']['tmp_name']);
    $files = $_FILES['uploadedimages'];
    for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++) {
      if($_FILES['uploadedimages']['error'][$i] != 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('fileupload_check', 'At least 1 image needed.');
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
      $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['uploadedimage']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['uploadedimage']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['uploadedimage']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];
      $this->upload->initialize($config);
      if ($this->upload->do_upload('uploadedimage')) {
        $this->_uploaded[$i] = $this->upload->data();
      } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('fileupload_check', $this->upload->display_errors());
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
    return TRUE;
  }
```

How do I save the path for each image in db if I have a field in tabel 'images_path'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In if condition Try this code.

```
$data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
$image_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
```

and if you print $data like this:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
```

you will get whole array which  includes path , name , image tyepe etc.

Comment: Thanks @Jaydeep B... When I do `$data['files'] = $this->_uploaded[$i] = $this->upload->data();`
`$image_name = $data['upload_data'][file_name];`
`echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);` It says "Use of undefined constant file_name - assumed 'file_name".

Comment: See updated answer. I forgot to put single quotes. and why you used $data['files'] = $this->_uploaded[$i] = $this->upload->data(); ?? simple assigned array value like my code.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain.. But is my code above in question correct at all? Because now it says "Illegal string offset 'name'" for `$_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];`.

Comment: many things wrong. First tell me , in view you used dynamic fields for multiple file upload OR single for select multiple file?

Comment: Thanks @jaydeep.. It's fixed now.. One more thing if you can help?.. It shows all array results fine now but with "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:" at the bottom any Idea? I am new to php as well Codeigniter.

Comment: Just comment which data we print. like this;  //echo "<pre>";print_r($data);  remember this output error occured when we print something and forgot to comment that.